# angularjs ui-router parent state resolves with each child state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent state that is never navigated to:

```
function wizard($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home.category', configureCategoryRoute());

    function configureCategoryRoute() {
        return {
            url: ':categoryName?g',
            views: {
                '@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/wizard/wizard.html',
                    controller: 'WizardController',
                    controllerAs: 'controller'
                },
                'menu@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/menu/menu.html',
                    controller: 'MenuController',
                    controllerAs: 'controller'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                options: getOptions,
                category: ['$stateParams', 'categoryService', function ($stateParams, categoryService) {
                    console.log('once');
                    return categoryService.get($stateParams.categoryName);
                }],
                criteria: ['category', 'criteriaService', function (category, criteriaService) {
                    return criteriaService.list(category.id, 'attributes');
                }],
                groups: ['category', 'wizardService', function (category, wizardService) {
                    return wizardService.listGroups(category.id);
                }],
                products: ['category', 'wizardService', function (category, wizardService) {
                    return wizardService.listProducts(category.id);
                }],
                questions: ['category', 'groups', 'criteria', 'questionProvider', function (category, groups, criteria, questionProvider) {
                    return questionProvider.list(category, groups, criteria, 'answers.formulas');
                }],
                settings: ['settingService', function (settingService) {
                    return settingService.list();
                }],
                decode: ['$stateParams', 'questions', 'encoder', 'questionProvider', function ($stateParams, questions, encoder, questionProvider) {
                    var simpleGroups = encoder.decode($stateParams.g);

                    return questionProvider.applyAnswers(questions, simpleGroups);
                }]
            }
        };
    };

    function getOptions($location) {
        return {
            matches: $location.search().matches === '1',
            showHeader: $location.search().showHeader === '1'
        };
    };
};
```

Then I have a set of child states:

```
function stepOne($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home.category.one', configureOneRoute());

    function configureOneRoute() {
        return {
            url: '/one',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/one/one.html',
                    controller: 'StepOneController',
                    controllerAs: 'controller'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                score: ['wizardService', 'groups', 'products', 'decode', function (wizardService, groups, products) {
                    return wizardService.score(groups, products);
                }]
            },
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Step one'
            }
        };
    };
};

function stepTwo($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home.category.two', configureTwoRoute());

    function configureTwoRoute() {
        return {
            url: '/two',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/two/two.html',
                    controller: 'StepTwoController',
                    controllerAs: 'controller'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                score: ['wizardService', 'groups', 'products', 'decode', function (wizardService, groups, products) {
                    return wizardService.score(groups, products);
                }]
            },
            data: {
                requireLogin: true,
                pageTitle: 'Step two'
            }
        };
    };
};
```

So step one and two are a child of wizard. Wizard cannot be navigated to (it will always go to step 1 first). The weird issue here is that, the **console.log('once')** fires every time we move from step 1 to 2, but I don't think it should. I was certain that parent state resolves are only fired if you change out of their state (like going to a completely different state that is not a child of the wizard).

I guess the questions here are: Am I wrong? Do parent state resolves resolve after any state change (regardless if they are children or not) or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: When a child state loads, the parent's resolves get resolved. That is intentional.

Comment: you misunderstand the issue, but it doesn't matter now. I know what is causing it.